How to remove sliding shower door hardware
Im trying to remove the towel rack and rail tracks on the shower door. There's a small hole like this (this is the shower door rail track, but the end cap of the towel rack also has hole like this), but seems like it's not for allen wrench. Any idea what's this, and how to remove?
Thanks


Try inserting a small screwdriver into the hole and turning the cap.

It worked! Thank you!

@RMDman sounds like you should make that answer :)

Try inserting a small screwdriver into the hole and turning the cap.
